# Wanted script tag elements of child in parent HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are 2 html files: `abcd.html` and `xyz.html`.

**abcd.html:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div> <!-- src= xyz.html only body of it is taken--> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**xyz.html:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="radio" id="radio">
    </body>
</html>
```

The file: `xyz.html`, contains a radio button and I need to style it using jQuery; however, the following jQuery code in both `xyz.html` and `abcd.html` is not working:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        styleRadio("radio");
    });
</script>
/* for this function styleRadio, the paramater passed is name parameter of the Radio button
function styleRadio(radioName){
        var radioButton = $('input[name="'+ radioName +'"]');
        $(radioButton).each(function(){
            $(this).wrap( "<span class='custom-radio'></span>" );
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
            }
        });
        $(radioButton).click(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
            }
            $(radioButton).not(this).each(function(){
                $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
            });
        });
    }
```

**css:**

```css
.custom-radio{
 width: 16px;
 height: 16px;
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
 top: 3px;
 background: url("../images/radio.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-radio:hover{            
 background: url("../images/radio-hover.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-radio.selected{
 background: url("../images/radio-selected.png") no-repeat;
}
.custom-radio input[type="radio"]{
 margin: 1px;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;            
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 opacity: 0;
 /* CSS hacks for older browsers */
 _noFocusLine: expression(this.hideFocus=true); 
 -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 -khtml-opacity: 0;
 -moz-opacity: 0;
}
```

The Div in the `abcd.html` is loaded with the body of `xyz.html`, on click of a link in the `abcd.html`.

Comment: You probably want to include the definition for styleRadio.

Comment: Expand a little more on what code you've written and why you think it should work. Tell us what has happened instead of the code working properly.

Comment: How you trying to style the radio? What is `styleRadio("radio");`

Comment: I have submitted an edit to your post, but in the future please take more time to properly format your code (be sure to use correct indentation). Also be sure to use correct punctutation and grammar. As a native English speaker, I know that nothing is more distracting that reading a paragraph with no uppercase letters.

Comment: It looks like the function `styleRadio` does all the work. For us to help you figure out why it's not working, we need to see that function.

Comment: Question is editted by adding **JS** and **css**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

```
function styleRadio(id) {
   $(id).css('opacity','0.5');
}
```

You'll need to use:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        styleRadio("#radio");
    });
</script>
```

with both blocks inside the `abcd.html`, because your `xyz.html` is never used as html, hence never interpreted.